# Efficient pattern search from a buffer in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, buffer

I've been trying to figure out an efficient way to work without reading twice from a file when using a buffer to search for a pattern of bytes. I've chosen to implement Runnable so I can divide my task to work in concurrent threads. My code looks something like this:

```
// constructor: initializes local variables.
public BytePatternSearcher(RandomAccessFile raFile, byte[] pattern, int bufferSize, long startPos, long endPos);

public void run()
{
    while(amountToRead - raFile.read(buffer) > 0)
    {
        // search code
    }
{
```

Now, I've hit a snag: my algorithm works in simple cases, but not in complex ones. I made the assumption that there are no cases of a pattern starting within one already being searched, that the pattern length is shorter than the buffer, and so on, limiting to one scan at a time and just iterating through the file. Naturally, this is not a very robust solution. Suppose I have a pattern of 'xxxxx' (length 5), my file is 'xxxxxxyxxxxxx' and my buffer size is 2 (x and y represent certain byte values). The string appears 4 times, and each check requires more than twice the buffer length.

How do I go about working things out without checking the same byte more than once for all cases?

Comment: Look up Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm.

Comment: i don't think the "design-pattern" tag is applicable

Comment: Adding multiple threads at this point is almost certainly premature optimization, and quite likely to give you out-of-memory errors as you try to load the entire file into memory at once. Instead, use a sequential algorithm (B-M is a good choice), keep track of matches, and either (1) process them as your find them, or (2) don't worry about reading the file twice (because many of its blocks are likely in an OS buffer).

Comment: @kdgregory this is a theoretical practice for me. I want to work with memory and thread constraints to eek out the maximum performance. But basically, the idea is to split it up to X threads, X being the amount of available cores, with total memory / X for memory use, and each thread will get 1/X of the file to handle - I will just send pointers for each thread of where to start and end the search.

Comment: In that case, here's two pieces practical advice: First: a single core can perform a linear scan of bytes faster than any disk can provide those bytes; you gain a performance benefit by passing high-CPU work to background threads while the mean thread finds that work. Second: it's better to be slow and correct, than fast and wrong. And if you don't handle data that crosses boundaries, you code is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia has an entry for [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) which also contains some sample implementations.